# No play button in Unit Test in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, testing, xctest

Sometimes the play button [image]disappears in Xcode when I want to make a Unit Test (XCTest). For instance there should be a play button to the left of testNSStringUtilities below but there is none. What can I do to get the play button to appear. It seems that sometimes cutting the method and pasting it again helps to get the play button back.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Usually the play buttons appear once you have run your unit tests completely (using Cmd U for example).

There are some more obscure cases, but usually this is all you have to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an Xcode bug, and it happens to me occasionally.

If those buttons are still not shown after you tried @Gerd's solution (like my case, Xcode 14.2), find the "Test Navigator" at Xcode's left sidebar, and click the run button of the expected test case to test.

Screenshot below:

[image]

And btw, you can use combo <kbd>Ctr</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to run the same test case again.

Answer (score 0):

**XCode 14+**

1. place your cursor into Test Case you want to run
2. press `⌃ ⌥ ⌘ U (control + option + command + U)`

after:  Corresponding Test Case is running ✅